# Requests library does not perform HTTP requests inside mitmproxy

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, mitmproxy

I installed mitmproxy by using pip (pip(3) install mitmproxy). I created a script that performs HTTP requests - I use https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/ obviously - on a specific trigger (e.g. an image or file went through the reverse proxy).

Versions: Python 3.9.1 for Windows 10 64 bits, pip version 20.2.3, and mitmproxy 6.0.2.

```
@staticmethod
def _file_exists(file_name: str) -> bool:
    request_path = "https://<url>/{}".format(file_name)
    req = requests.get(request_path) # import requests

    return True if req.status_code == 200 else False
```

This blocks forever if I use the command `mitmdump -s script.py`. Adding a timeout will result in a TCP timeout exception - for HTTP and TLS.

I tried the following:

- Re-installing the SSL certificate of mitmproxy
- Using a clean Windows installation
- I tried to connect to an IP address
- I tried to connect without HTTPS

I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you perhaps have iptables configured to that outgoing requests from mitmproxy are picked up as well? That would create an infinite loop.

Comment: I don't think so. I disabled iptables - in my case Windows Firewall. It still blocks forever. I disabled every program I can think of that could be doing something like that.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your script. It will block mitmproxy's entire main thread (https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/blob/master/examples/addons/nonblocking.py), but not forever. Can you post the full script?

Comment: Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/merjn/fc0adbb9035fa54609b0af6c1a32e5b1. Tool.py contains the misbehavior. Other two files are here to show you what happens. To clarify, I use an observer that notifies the chain of responsibility. FurniExistsHandler is the first to be executed.

Comment: That looks pretty convoluted, sorry. Here's a minimal example with requests that works fine for me: https://gist.github.com/mhils/5aa323bcb698c9382f6cb436b3bfcfba

Comment: Your script is still blocking: https://prnt.sc/yt1bbm

Comment: How did you solve the problem @Merijn? I'm trying with mitmproxy and getting the same issue.